# Global onBlur/onFocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

We have, like everyone else, forms all over our web app.

So far we've been using the following (or some variation) in most every form element:

```
class="formThingy"    
onFocus="document.theForm.theField.className='formThingySelected';" 
onBlur="document.theForm.theField.className='formThingy';"
```

It's a pain.
Is there an easy way to do get the same result with either javascript/jQuery or CSS?

I know in css we can use things like :hover but that doesn't get what we're looking for.

My guess is that there is something we can do with jQuery that looks at everything with a class of 'FormThingy" and changes it onFocus and back onBlur, I'm just not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.formThingy').bind('focus blur', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('formThingy formThingySelected');
});
```

Comment: blur and focus are currently unsupported by `live` :(

Comment: Wow, you're right. I had forgotten that! In that case I recommend the first version :)

Comment: I ended up using this method since I could focus it on the .formThingy class items.  I also had a class of .formThingyLogin & .formThingyLoginSelected that the other method was causing problems with so doing this allowed me to better target both situations.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you could accomplish the same thing with:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    $(this).attr('class', 'formThingySelected');
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).attr('class', 'formThingy');
});
```

You might want to adjust the selector for better performance.  The selector should match all elements you wish to attach the focus/blur behavior to.

Comment: So, if I wanted to do this to all <input> and <select> tags I would have to add this in twice?  Really, I only want this bot <input>, <select> and <textarea>.

Comment: then an appropriate selector would then be `'input, select, textarea'`

Comment: So I have to ask...is there a performance difference between your answer and Alex's or is the difference just a matter of style?

Comment: I would say the use of `.formThingy` as a selector over tag names would be slightly more performant. Also, using jQuery's native class manipulation methods over `attr` is more flexible as it won't overwrite other class names. More importantly though, I win at golf :)

Comment: I'm not 100% confident about this, but I seem to recall selectors against tags take advantage of browser apis to get elements by tag.  Some best-practices recommend prepending .class selectors whenever possible.  If you only want to apply it to input elements of `formThingy` then my money is on $('input.formThingy') outperforming $('.formThingy').

Comment: You can try it, but I also have my doubts. Aside from the fact that modern browsers implement the `getElementsByClassName()` method, combining the two selectors forces jQuery to do more work. But as always, the only way to find out is to run benchmarks. Also, this is a prime example of premature optimization.

Comment: @alex: yes, its definitely that